# pyGame image scale does not work as expected

Tags: python, image, pygame, transform, scale

I am new into Python and pyGame and i have a problem with scaling an image.
I want to zoom an image in pygame.
The pygame documentation claims that

> pygame.transform.scale()

should scale to a new resolution.
But in my example below it does not work - it crops the image instead of resizing it!?
What am i doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))

pic = pygame.image.load('test.jpg').convert()
pic_position_and_size = pic.get_rect()

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Clear event queue
pygame.event.clear()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                done = True

    # background in black
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Copy image to screen:
    screen.blit(pic, pic_position_and_size)

    # Update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.delay(10)    # stop the program for 1/100 second

    # decreases size by 1 pixel in x and y axis
    pic_position_and_size = pic_position_and_size.inflate(-1, -1)

    # scales the image
    pic = pygame.transform.scale(pic, pic_position_and_size.size)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pygame.transform.scale()` does not work very well for your case. If you shrink a `Surface` by such a small amount, the algorithm just crops the last column and row of pixels. If you now repeat this process over and over again with the same `Surface`, you get the strange behaviour you see.

A better approach would be to keep a copy of your original `Surface` around, and use that for creating the scaled image. Also, using `smoothscale` instead of `scale` may also lead to a better effect; it's up to you if you want to use it.

Here's a "fixed" version of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))

org_pic = pygame.image.load('test.jpg').convert()
pic_position_and_size = org_pic.get_rect()
pic = pygame.transform.scale(org_pic, pic_position_and_size.size)
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Clear event queue
pygame.event.clear()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                done = True

    # background in black
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Copy image to screen:
    screen.blit(pic, (0,0))

    # Update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.delay(10)    # stop the program for 1/100 second

    # decreases size by 1 pixel in x and y axis
    pic_position_and_size = pic_position_and_size.inflate(-1, -1)

    # scales the image
    pic = pygame.transform.smoothscale(org_pic, pic_position_and_size.size)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! Solved my problem! However, i wonder why this is not mentioned in the pygame documentation... took me hours to play around with and i tried everything...